# Should "logging in" be considered a use case?

Tags: authentication, use-case

I've witnessed a number of debates regarding this question, and have seen a few inconclusive discussions online as well. The debate just sparked up between students in my Software Architecture and Design course, and I'd like to hear some thoughts from a more knowledgeable perspective.

So my question is simple: Should "logging in" be considered a use case? Is there a definitive answer to this, or is it something that will always welcome debate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I think that here is not a good space for debate, because of the site format and rules, I think this is a valid question. At first I wondered why not considering logging in as a use case. So, I google it and found that [enlightening discussion](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.7340.13). Now it is clear to me. There is no easy answer. It also depends on the level of the use case modelling. At the requirement eliciting, logging in is not a use case, but at the [system design level](http://sunnyday.mit.edu/16.355/requirements-notes.pdf) it might appear as a use case . If security is a concern, it must appear and be treated as a special use case.

Comment: The discussion link is down.